# How to run delegate_to task only on one host in group with if/when condition?

Tags: ansible

My host file looks like below where I am using specific host variables `smca_role`.

```
[smca]
smca1 ansible_host=10.66.69.194 smca_role=True
smca2 ansible_host=10.66.69.193 smca_role=False
```

My playbook looks like below. I am delegating a task to the above `smca` group and it is going to run on both the hosts which I don't want.

```
---
- hosts:smsm
  tasks:
    - name: Check the flag for smca role
      shell: *****Some Command*****
      register: enable_result
      delegate_to: '{{ item }}'
      with_items: '{{ groups.smca }}'
```

**My problem:** I want to run it on only one host which matches the condition `smca_role=True`.  How can I use Jinja2 template & put if/when condition inside `with_items: {{ groups.smca }}` so that it runs only on the required host?

**Notes:**

1. Using plain when condition won't work in my case as the playbook is run on another host group `smsm` where I'm gathering/setting facts and I'm using those facts when delegating it to `smca` host group.
2. `{{ groups.smca[0] }}` won't work in my case as there is no guarantee that always the first host will have that condition true it can keep changing & `smca` group can have more than 2 hosts.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Using plain when condition won't work in my case

It will work if you use the condition:

```
when: "{{ hostvars[item]['smca_role'] }}"
```

Comment: Hi I tried using this condition but it is running on all the hosts under smca. I want it to run on only host which has "smca_role=True"

Comment: when: "{{ hostvars[item]['smca_role'] }}" In the mentioned condition, we are not specifying whether it should run for flag True/False ? How can we add that ? I tried when: "{{ hostvars[item]['smca_role== True'] }}" (Didn't work)

Comment: No. You don't need to use comparison for Booleans. Your condition makes no sense, so it did not work; use the one provided in the answer.